# Generate Typedoc output with parent module name

Tags: typescript, typedoc

I have a Node.js (TypeScript) package that is laid out as follows:

```
hello-world
   `-index.ts
   `- child-module
       `- index.ts
```

When I generate documentation for this package using Typedoc, it creates documentation for modules `index` and `child-module/index`. Instead, can I get it to list the modules as `hello-world` and `hello-world/child-module`?